# Google App Script's time-driven trigger is not firing/executing a function that works otherwise when manually running it

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, v8

I have created a manual time-driven trigger that runs the function `sendScheduledEmails` every 30 minutes. See image below. Failure notification is set to notify me immediately if it fails.

[image: Manual time-driven trigger settings]

[image: No results for any executions related to the trigger I've created]

Despite this trigger having existed all day, there are no executions (neither failed or successful) and I have received no failure notifications.

I'm confused why this trigger isn't even *firing* the function? If it did, I'm assuming it would be a failed execution, but that way I'd be able to understand what's preventing the function from working. Not sure how to debug this without the time-driven trigger not even firing.

The function `sendScheduledEmails` works as desired when I run it using the "Run" function button on my script.google.com `gs` file.

[image]

I have crawled these SO pages to fix it. The main issues I noted were:

1. Permissions. My account has gone through the "Allow" pop-up many times that comes up around this script. My account has "Editor" access to the corresponding spreadsheet. See below image for more detailed view of permissions I have in regards to this sheet / script.
2. Using `getActiveSheet()` instead of `openById()`. I have changed this for my script, see below.
3. [Using Array methods](https://groups.google.com/g/google-apps-script-community/c/xoC-A9cpoyE?pli=1), specifically `Filter`. I have changed this for my script, see below.
4. Can't find Gmail Template because subject line has tiny typo / error. I have copied and pasted the subject line from the draft sitting in my inbox. And the fact that this script works when I manually run, tells me that this isn't the issue.

Despite changing all this, my time-driven trigger does not fire. I've tried an hourly trigger, a 30-minute trigger, a specific date & time one-time trigger, etc. In a different spreadsheet & script, I made the above changes, and I was able to have the time-driven trigger to fire correctly. I appreciate your help trying to debug why it doesn't work for this spreadsheet / script.

[image: Image of Permissions for this script / sheet]

```javascript
/**
 * Change these to match the column names you are using for email 
 * recipient addresses and email sent column.
*/
const RECIPIENT_COL  = "SupervisorRecipient";
const SPREADSHEET_ID = "17SggU5Avv8ZWcq0F7_k4jxLdsqzI7qpFMGM9ANH_Bio";
const SUBJECT_LINE = 'Monthly Report: {{Date1}} - {{Date2}}';
 
/** 
 * Creates the menu item "Mail Merge" for user to run scripts on drop-down.
 */
function onOpen() {
  const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Mail Merge')
      .addItem('Send Preliminary Emails', 'sendScheduledEmails')
      .addToUi();
}

function sendScheduledEmails() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SPREADSHEET_ID);
    const sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
    sendEmails(sheet);
}

/**
 * Sends emails from sheet data.
 * @param {string} subjectLine (optional) for the email draft message
 * @param {Sheet} sheet to read data from
*/
function sendEmails(sheet) {
  // Gets the draft Gmail message to use as a template
  const emailTemplate = getGmailTemplateFromDrafts_(SUBJECT_LINE);
  
  // Gets the data from the passed sheet
  const data = sheet.getDataRange().getDisplayValues();

  // Assumes row 1 contains our column headings
  const heads = data.shift(); 
  
  // Converts 2d array into an object array
  // See https://stackoverflow.com/a/22917499/1027723
  // For a pretty version, see https://mashe.hawksey.info/?p=17869/#comment-184945
  const obj = data.map(r => (heads.reduce((o, k, i) => (o[k] = r[i] || '', o), {})));

  // Creates an array to record sent emails
  const out = [];

  // Loops through all the rows of data
  obj.forEach(function(row, rowIdx){
    // Only sends emails if email_sent cell is blank and not hidden by a filter
    if (row[RECIPIENT_COL]){
      try {
        const msgObj = fillInTemplateFromObject_(emailTemplate.message, row);

        // See https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#sendEmail(String,String,String,Object)
        // If you need to send emails with unicode/emoji characters change GmailApp for MailApp
        // Uncomment advanced parameters as needed (see docs for limitations)
        GmailApp.sendEmail(row[RECIPIENT_COL], msgObj.subject, msgObj.text, {
          htmlBody: msgObj.html,
          // bcc: 'a.bbc@email.com',
          // cc: 'a.cc@email.com',
          // from: 'an.alias@email.com',
          // name: 'name of the sender',
          // replyTo: 'a.reply@email.com',
          // noReply: true, // if the email should be sent from a generic no-reply email address (not available to gmail.com users)
          attachments: emailTemplate.attachments,
          inlineImages: emailTemplate.inlineImages
        });
        // Edits cell to record email sent date
        out.push([new Date()]);
      } catch(e) {
        // modify cell to record error
        out.push([e.message]);
      }
    }
  });

  /**
   * Get a Gmail draft message by matching the subject line.
   * @param {string} subject_line to search for draft message
   * @return {object} containing the subject, plain and html message body and attachments
  **/

  function getGmailTemplateFromDrafts_(subject_line){
    try {
      // get drafts
      var msg = null;
      const drafts = GmailApp.getDrafts();

      // filter the drafts that match subject line
      for (var i = 0;i<drafts.length;i++) {
        msg = drafts[i].getMessage();
        if(msg.getSubject() == subject_line) { break;}
      }
      
      // Handles inline images and attachments so they can be included in the merge
      // Based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/65813881/1027723
      // Gets all attachments and inline image attachments

      const allInlineImages = msg.getAttachments({includeInlineImages: true,includeAttachments:false});
      const attachments = msg.getAttachments({includeInlineImages: false});
      const htmlBody = msg.getBody(); 

      // Creates an inline image object with the image name as key 
      // (can't rely on image index as array based on insert order)
      const img_obj = allInlineImages.reduce((obj, i) => (obj[i.getName()] = i, obj) ,{});

      //Regexp searches for all img string positions with cid
      const imgexp = RegExp('<img.*?src=cid:(.*?).*?alt="(.*?)"[^\>]+>', 'g');
      const matches = [...htmlBody.matchAll(imgexp)];

      //Initiates the allInlineImages object
      const inlineImagesObj = {};

      // built an inlineImagesObj from inline image matches
      matches.forEach(match => inlineImagesObj[match[1]] = img_obj[match[2]]);

      return {message: {subject: subject_line, text: msg.getPlainBody(), html:htmlBody}, 
              attachments: attachments, inlineImages: inlineImagesObj };
    } catch(e) {
      throw new Error("Oops - can't find Gmail draft");
    }
  }
  
  /**
   * Fill template string with data object
   * @see https://stackoverflow.com/a/378000/1027723
   * @param {string} template string containing {{}} markers which are replaced with data
   * @param {object} data object used to replace {{}} markers
   * @return {object} message replaced with data
  */
  function fillInTemplateFromObject_(template, data) {
    // We have two templates one for plain text and the html body
    // Stringifing the object means we can do a global replace
    let template_string = JSON.stringify(template);

    // Token replacement
    template_string = template_string.replace(/{{[^{}]+}}/g, key => {
      return escapeData_(data[key.replace(/[{}]+/g, "")] || "");
    });
    return JSON.parse(template_string);
  }

  /**
   * Escape cell data to make JSON safe
   * @see https://stackoverflow.com/a/9204218/1027723
   * @param {string} str to escape JSON special characters from
   * @return {string} escaped string
  */
  function escapeData_(str) {
    return str
      .replace(/[\\]/g, '\\\\')
      .replace(/[\"]/g, '\\\"')
      .replace(/[\/]/g, '\\/')
      .replace(/[\b]/g, '\\b')
      .replace(/[\f]/g, '\\f')
      .replace(/[\n]/g, '\\n')
      .replace(/[\r]/g, '\\r')
      .replace(/[\t]/g, '\\t');
  };
}
```

Comment: I believe that in `GmailApp.sendEmail("row[RECIPIENT_COL]", msgObj.subject, msgObj.text, {
          htmlBody: msgObj.html,`  that "row[RECIPIENT_COL]"  should not be in quotes.

Comment: Great catch, so sorry, that was a typo from me transferring the code to this post. In my actual code it doesn't have quotes around it.

Comment: Have you tested all of the drafts in manual?

Comment: This `'<img.*?src=cid:(.*?).*?alt="(.*?)"[^\>]+>', 'g')` regex looks like something I received help with recently I won't mention who from but their excessive use of `.*` can lead to sucking up a lot more stuff than you really might want to.  So I would take a close look at that.  I think I could solve this problem with the debugger but it might take me a while.  Without all of the code and drafts to run I don't think I can do it.  And I also would not wish to go to your spreadsheet because I don't wish to disclose my email.  So sorry I cannot help more.